# SAS: Combining two data sets with different format

Tags: merge, sas, dataset

I have two datasets that are formatted differently

data1 looks like:

```
data1:

YYMM  test1
1101  98
1102  98
1103  94
1104  92
1105  99
1106  91
```

data 2 is just a single grand mean that looks like:

```
data2:

GM
95
```

I would like to combine the two and have something that looks like this:

```
WANT:

YYMM  test1  GM
1101  98     95
1102  98     95
1103  94     95
1104  92     95
1105  99     95
1106  91     95
```

I'm sure there are different ways to go about configuring this but I thought I should make the 95 into a column and merge with data1.

Do I have to use macro for this simple task? Please show me some light!

Comment: How are you creating the mean? One way you could do this and avoid creating a tiny dataset and a merge is to get that mean into a macro variable (called mean in this example) and then simply do: data data3; set data1; GM = &mean.; run; -- besides that you can just do data data3; merge data1 data2; run; and it should work

Comment: I don't believe that is correct @scott, concerning your last suggestion. SAS only hangs on to the last record when you use a by-statement. (the last record of each by group in that case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way is to just merge without by statement and the use of retain:

```
data WANT (drop=temp);
    merge DATA1 DATA2 (rename=(GM=temp));
    retain GM;
    if _N_=1 then GM=temp;
run;
```

So basically you put the two datasets together.
Because there is no by-statement, it will join together the first record of both datasets, the second record of both datasets and so on.

At the first record (if *N*=1), you grab the average and you put it in a variable for which the last value will be remembered (retain GM).
So in record 2, 3 etc, the value will still be what you put into it at record 1.

To keep it all clean, i renamed your GM variable on the input, so it was available to use as name for the retained variable. And of course, i dropped the redundant variable.

You can also approach this issue with a macro variable or a proc sql. But better keep it simple.

Comment: IT WORKED. Wow. That was easy. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Where does _N_ come from? Is it one of the hidden variables? Also, why is it 1?

Comment: `_N_` is an internal value equal to the number of iterations the data step has performed. 'Usually' on a simple 'set', this equates to the row number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar way that's slightly simpler.

```
data want;
set data1;
if _n_=1 then set data2;
run;
```